# Automated storing of Image URLs in a database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have been trying to create smoothly functioning image preview for each website URL, on hover, using the [websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com) service. The javascript below works great, but generates a website preview on the fly, which is very slow, and seems unnecessary because I am always working with the same database entries, and this method may generate the image preview for the SAME website multiple times (on every refresh), when in actuality only once will suffice, as long as I have and can store the image path in a DB for later use.

The database I am working with contains 3,000+ website URL's. I would like to create a thumbnail image preview for each of these in an automated way, using a PHP script and by storing the `websnapr` image paths in the database, so they can later be used to generate website previews in a more efficient way. However, this is a bit over my skill level...

I appreciate any suggestions how to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

JavaScript

```
$('.co-website').each(function(){
    var url = encodeURIComponent($(this).children('a').attr('href'));

    var imgSRC = 'http://images.websnapr.com/?url=' + url + '&key=' + apiKey + '&hash=' + encodeURIComponent(websnapr_hash);
    $(this).children('a').attr("title", "<img src='"+imgSRC+"' />");
});
```

PHP Script

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $thumbnail_url = 'http://images.websnapr.com/?url=' . $row['website'] . '&key='.$apiKey.'&hash='.; 
    //Not sure how to get the hash portion of the URL
}
//update this record's thumbnail mySQL field
```

Comment: You're trying to get a PHP variable value from JS? If so, you can't do that.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code, and inputs/outputs?  There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: What input / outputs would you like to see, what relevant code is missing?? If you look at the code, the JS code successfully creates an image path. I am trying iterate through all websites in the database and create images paths, in a similar way, and store these image paths in the database so I can later retrieve them...

Comment: Well, for a start, where does the magical `websnapr_hash` variable in your JavaScript come from? Esp. as that's the question you're asking about the PHP...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I believe that is generated in the included JavaScript code that must be imported for use of the plugin. It can be found here: http://www.websnapr.com/js/websnapr.js

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. Why do you think storing pre-generated websnapr "image paths" (I assume you mean URLs) will be any faster? 2. If you're looking to cache the output of the websnapr service and reuse it, what do the websnapr terms of service have to say about that?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend: *"I believe that is generated in the included..."* Ah, okay, I had a quick look at their website and didn't see it. (Mind you, the demo on the front page of the site isn't working right now, either, so...)

Comment: Their terms and services does not cover `caching`. I do believe it will be faster, because the javascript implementation above seems to generate a new screen shot every time the page is refreshed even if its for the same URL, this takes some time. This is why I believe that storing the image path will save the time of a creating and rendering a new image preview using the `websnapr` service everytime the page is refreshed. In other words, my plan is to use the `websnapr` service once only for every URL and then store and reuse the image path / URL in a database, rather than recreating...

Comment: Have you considered using Ajax to pass the completed url to a php script which will insert it into the database after you make the request to websnapr?

Comment: Yes, I have but I'm not exactly sure how to do it and not sure if it'll even work because of the `websnapr_hash` may expire...